# Ubuntu and Windows Dual Boot Clock Problem

Tags: windows-8, 14.10, time, clock

I have gone through the various threads regarding this, but surprisingly /etc/default/rcS contains UTC=no by default for me.

Now I've no idea what should I do next?

I'm using Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.10 and the time difference is around +/- 6 Hours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 15.10 assumes BIOS clock is set to UTC time regardless of UTC=no in /etc/default/rcS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720445/ubuntu-15-10-assumes-bios-clock-is-set-to-utc-time-regardless-of-utc-no-in-etc)

Comment: what is the time shown in BIOS? is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the top of the page click on the Time and it will show you the calender and where you are supposedly located, underneath that if you click on the Time and Date settings you can manually set the time from there.

Comment: Well, I guess you didn't understand my problem. I'll state it in details.

When I boot to Ubuntu it shows correct time (as it syncs with internet).

When I boot to Windows it shows wrong time (as I have previously booted to Ubuntu) and when I sync with internet, it shows correct time.

Again, if I boot to Ubuntu, then Ubuntu shows wrong time, and again on sync it shows correct time.

So, the summary is, whichever OS I boot first shows correct time and the 2nd OS I boot into shows wrong time and I have to sync it manually.

And on both the OS, my TimeZone and Location is Ok.

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu updates the time from internet, so Ubuntu’s time is correct. Check your windows time and compare with internet time and change it manually.

If the problem persists then change the time in windows boot menu. Otherwise check your semiconductor battery (which is used for time in any computers). If the battery power is down the computers time changes often, you can avoid this by changing the battery it costs nearly 10 to 20 rupees.

Hope you understand the answer, if you have any doubt comment below .

Comment: Well, I guess you didn't understand my problem. I'll state it in details.

When I boot to Ubuntu it shows correct time (as it syncs with internet).

When I boot to Windows it shows wrong time (as I have previously booted to Ubuntu) and when I sync with internet, it shows correct time.

Again, if I boot to Ubuntu, then Ubuntu shows wrong time, and again on sync it shows correct time.

So, the summary is, whichever OS I boot first shows correct time and the 2nd OS I boot into shows wrong time and I have to sync it manually.

And on both the OS, my TimeZone and Location is Ok.