# closing ubuntu then restarting in windows, the clock is always 8 hours late

Tags: windows-10, clock

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and I regularly switch between Ubuntu and Windows 10. Every time I switch to w10, the clock there is always 8 hours earlier. Since it's a one way problem I can only guess there is something in Ubuntu that I need to fix. What might cause this?

Comment: Many versions of Linux assume that the BIOS/UEFI should be set to UTC time. As a result, booting into a modern Linux distribution will set the system's internal clock accordingly. Windows, as one would expect, does their own thing when reading and validating time. [This answer from a few years ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/762848/1222991) may give you want you need to keep the two OSes in sync.

Comment: Try `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`